# Changing coordinates in partial derivatives, re: Hydrogen atom

Tags: quantum-mechanics, differentiation, hydrogen

At around 11:35 in this video

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q99ygFeWGv4

the instructor is using a  "standard way of changing
coordinates"  in partial derivatives relating to
the new variables of the Center Of Mass of the hydrogen
atom  (electron & proton)  and the Relative Position of
the electron vs. proton.

$x_e$ is the $x$-coordinate of the electron.

$x_p$ is the $x$-coordinate of the proton.

$X$ is the $x$-coordinate of the center of mass of the
electron-proton pair.

$x$ is the $x$-coordinate of the relative position of
the electron vs. proton  ($x_e - x_p$).

He writes:

$$\partial/\partial x_e |_{x_p} = (\partial X/\partial x_e) |_{x_p} \cdot (\partial/\partial X) |_{x}  + (\partial x/\partial x_e) |_{x_p} \cdot (\partial/\partial x) |_{X}$$

where the  $|_{x_p}$  means, for example,  "with the
position of the proton held constant".

In the term  $(\partial/\partial X) |_{x}$, why is the thing being
held constant $x$  (the relative position of electron
and proton)  and not $x_p$?

Comment: Why some people ( not you user4127427) confuse us by this way ???  The partial derivative $\:\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial x_k} \;$ of a function $\:F\left(x_1,x_2,\cdots ,x_n\right)\:$  with respect to $x_k$ means exactly that : change of  $\:F\:$ as $x_k$ only changes with all other variables unchanged.  What is the need for all these vertical bars ??? See the simplicity of above expression

$\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_e} =\dfrac{\partial}{\partial X}\dfrac{\partial X}{\partial x_e} + \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial x_e}$

Comment: (8/11/2015)  I changed my user name from that user4127427 thing to a00 in my profile.  The user4127427 is what StackExchange originally randomly assigned to me and I didn't think until now that I could fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an ideal, theoretical world, we would only have functions from $m$ arguments to some space, and we'd say "the partial derivative with respect to the $n^{\text{th}}$ argument", with an implicit statement "holding all the other $m - 1$ arguments constant." Call this derivative of a function $f(x_1, \dots, x_m)$ the derivative $f_{n}$.

But, we live in a complicated world, and sometimes we struggle with the case:$$u(a, b) = f\big(g(a, b), h(a, b)\big)$$where we want to take the derivative with respect to $a$ while holding $b$ constant. This can be viewed as a "change of coordinates" from $a, b$ to $g, h$. The derivatives are simply given by the chain rule acting on $a$ pretending that $b$ is a constant, hence:$$u_1 = \left.{\partial f\over\partial a}\right|_b = f_1\big(g(a,b), h(a, b)\big)~g_1(a, b) + f_2\big(g(a,b), h(a, b)\big)~h_1(a, b).$$The awkward notation "holding this thing constant" comes from the desire to not specifically define $u$ every single time we do this sort of thing. In particular we find ourselves writing $f_1(g, h)$ as $$f_1\big(g(a,b), h(a, b)\big) = \left.{\partial f\over\partial g}\right|_h,$$ which in some ways makes a lot of sense (treating these symbols as abstract entities in their own right) and in some ways doesn't (looking at this thing as a function). We basically have said "there is some freedom in how we vary the output of $f$, we can either vary $g$ and $h$ or we can vary $a$ and $b$," and now we have two different corresponding notions of "partial derivative" that we're condensing into one.

In any case when we make this "syntactic sugar" replacement we end up writing $$u_1 ~=~ \left.{\partial f\over\partial a}\right|_b ~=~ \left.{\partial f\over\partial g}\right|_h \cdot \left.{\partial g\over\partial a}\right|_b ~+~ \left.{\partial f\over\partial h}\right|_g \cdot \left.{\partial h\over\partial a}\right|_b $$In your case in particular, $a = x_e,~ b = x_p,~g=X,~h = x,$ and we are looking at some function $$u(x_e, x_p) = f\big(X(x_e, x_p),x(x_e, x_p)\big)$$ where the resulting expression is$$\left.{\partial f\over\partial x_e}\right|_{x_p} ~=~ \left.{\partial f\over\partial X}\right|_x \cdot \left.{\partial X\over\partial x_e}\right|_{x_p} ~+~ \left.{\partial f\over\partial x}\right|_{X} \cdot \left.{\partial x\over\partial x_e}\right|_{x_p}.$$

Now what would it mean to take $\partial f / \partial X$ while holding $x_e$ constant? It might sometimes not mean anything: think for example if $X = x_e$, or $x_e^2$, or something -- it might be nonsense! But suppose it is not, then we are saying that there is **yet another** way to view this system, with $x_p = x_p(X, x_e)$, so that we are looking not at $f$ but at some $f'(X, x_e)$. This is possible, but you see that usually you want to mentally slice the world into different "universes" of coordinates: these derivatives live in the $(X, x)$ universe; those derivatives live in the $(x_e, x_p)$ universe, let's not take derivatives with respect to the coordinates of one universe holding parameters in the other universe constant.

**If we change the parameters from this we'll usually get the wrong answer.** Let's take some simple example, $X = x_e + x_p$, $x = x_e - x_p$. Consider $f = 2 X - x$. Then done the "proper" way, $$\left.{\partial f\over\partial x_e}\right|_{x_p} = 2 \cdot \left.{\partial X\over\partial x_e}\right|_{x_p} - 
\left.{\partial x\over\partial x_e}\right|_{x_p} = 2 - 1 = 1.$$This sort of derivative corresponds to the obvious substitution $$f = 2 (x_e + x_p) - (x_e - x_p) = x_e + 3 x_p.$$(Go ahead, do the result for $\partial f/\partial x_p|_{x_e}$ and confirm that it's 3.)

But if we mix coordinates we rewrite $x_p = X - x_e$ and $x = 2 x_e - X$, we find $f = 3 X - 2 x_e,$ and if we do exactly what you're saying (replace the $2$ above in $2 - 1 = 1$ with this $-2$), we get an answer $-3$ which does not correspond to anything we know about the system.

Comment: It kind of makes sense but kind of doesn't.  Ultimately, we wish to find the change in the wave function $\Psi$ when we vary $x_e$ a bit but do NOT let the proton move  ($x_p$  may not change).  Since the change in the wave function value  (value of $\Psi$)  is contributed by the two parts, one part of change from the induced delta in $X$ and the other part from the induced delta in $x$, it makes sense to say  "Let's calculate the contribution from $X$ while holding $x$ fixed and also the contribution from $x$ while holding $X$ fixed and add the two to get the total alteration."  (Thanks to

Comment: your answer for helping me see that)   But:  since the ultimate goal is to find the change in $\Psi$ with a change in $x_e$ but no change in $x_p$, how can one calculate  "$(d\Psi/dX)$ with $x_p$ fixed AND $x$ fixed"?  It is possible to make $X$ move by adjusting $x_e$ but it is not possible to make $X$ move by adjusting $x_e$ AND keeping $x_p$ constant AND $x$ constant.

Comment: Right, what you've just described is impossible, and therefore incalculable. If you tell me you are keeping both $x_p$ and $x = x_e - x_p$ fixed, then *you are telling me by definition* that you are also keeping $x_e = x + x_p$ fixed and also $X = x_e + x_p = x + 2 x_p$. If you then ask me how $f$ varies with $X$, holding $X$ constant, I have to reply that it's a nonsense question and you can't vary anything with a variable while holding that variable constant, the words 'vary' and 'constant' have opposite meanings and you cannot have it both ways.

Comment: Good point.  I guess that's what you were explaining with the $f = 2X - x$ example.

Comment: Sorry;  I think you in your original answer answered all my confusions but it's just taking me a while to understand everything.

Comment: Okay, I worked through your example and I see that the muddling of the parameters leads to wrong results.  Hopefully soon I will have more of a grasp of exactly why.

Comment: @a00 If you're still lost, really just work it through the chain rule. Start with the basics: we vary some input to a function a little bit to see how the output varies: $f(x + dx) = f + df = f(x) + f'(x)~dx$. That's what a derivative means. Now a 'normal' partial derivative, $f(x + dx, y) = f(x, y) + f_x(x, y)~dx,$is analogous. But what if $x, y$ vary with some $a, b$? Then the partial with respect to $a$ holding $b$ constant is $f(x + dx, y + dy)$ where $dx = x_a(a, b)~da$ and $dy = y_a(a, b)~da$, both holding $b$ constant. This is the core of this complicated $f_x x_a + f_y y_a$ structure.

Comment: Your statement makes sense to me now.  I am now thinking of it like this:   change in wave function has 2 components.  The first is Change in $\Psi$ due to a small bump in $x_e$ inducing a change in center of mass = $(lim \Delta x_e \rightarrow 0) [ (d\Psi/dX)*(\Delta X/\Delta x_e) * \Delta x_e ]$.  Here we just "know"  (cheating)  that $d\Psi/dX$ is simple translation of the whole tortoiseshell like wave function of the hydrogen atom.

Comment: The second is Change in $\Psi$ due to a small bump in $x_e$ inducing a change in relative position of proton and electron i.e. stretch or compress the tortoiseshell = $(lim \Delta x_e \rightarrow 0) [ (d\Psi/dx) * (\Delta x/\Delta x_e) * \Delta x_e]$.  And we "know" that $d\Psi/dx$ will be just some sort of stretching or compressing of the tortoiseshell.  So now these two components adding up to the total change seems believable.

Comment: That's about it, yep. Awesome that you found a way to make it intuitive to you.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a function $f(x_e,x_p)$ then it has the partial derivative $\partial f/\partial x_e$ (that holds $x_p$ constant and treats the function like a 1d function of $x_e$ alone) and similarly has the partial derivatives $\partial f/\partial x_p$ (that holds $x_e$ constant and treats the function like a 1d function of $x_p$ alone).

But you can think of $x_e$ itself as a function of the center of mass $X$ and the relative displacement $x=x_e-x_p.$ Same for $x_p.$

So if you have $x_e=x_e(X,x)$ and $x_p=x_p(X,x)$ then the chain rule gives

$$\frac{\partial f }{\partial X}=\frac{\partial f }{\partial x_e}\frac{\partial x_e}{\partial X}+\frac{\partial f }{\partial x_p}\frac{\partial x_p}{\partial X},$$

and

$$\frac{\partial f }{\partial x}=\frac{\partial f }{\partial x_e}\frac{\partial x_e}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial f }{\partial x_p}\frac{\partial x_p}{\partial x}.$$

If instead you think of the potential as actually determined by the relative position x and the center of mass such as $V(x,X)=k/x$ then you might want to chain rule the other way to get

$$\frac{\partial V }{\partial x_e}=\frac{\partial V }{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial x_e}+\frac{\partial V}{\partial X}\frac{\partial X}{\partial x_e},$$

and

$$\frac{\partial V }{\partial x_p}=\frac{\partial V }{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial x_p}+\frac{\partial V}{\partial X}\frac{\partial X}{\partial x_p}.$$

And that last one doesn't have to be the potential, absolutely any function of $X$ and $x$ can be treated this way. So we can write the partial with respect to $x_e$ or $x_p$ as a local combination of the partials with $X$ and $x$ exactly like you mentioned.

It's just the chain rule for multivariate partial derivatives.

Comment: I feel there must be some sort of  "orthogonality"  between
the  "opposing"  variables.  i.e. $x_e$ is independent in some
sense of $x_p$ and the center of mass position is independent
of the separation between the proton and electron.  For this
all to work.

Comment: It is interesting to view the position of the electron as
a function of the center of mass position and separation
distance of proton from electron.  Thank you for the answer.